# Table to Table relationship in Google Relationship

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table, data-analysis, table-relationships

I am new to Google Sheet. I have a question regarding Pivot Table. I make table to table connection in Microsoft Excel when I work with multiple tables at Pivot Table option.

Is there same process in Google Sheet while working with Pivot Table feature? I cannot find any table relationship option in Google Sheet so far. What can I do if I have more than one table?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit the question to provide enough information for users to recreate your problem.